# TextView text cut off on the left instead of getting ellipsis-shortened

Tags: android-layout, android

Look at the part of the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/second_team_code"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                style="@style/TextView.TeamCode"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/second_team_flag"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                style="@style/FlagImageView"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

For some reason, when small size of enclosing views causes text to overflow, text is not shortened by adding "...", but the beginning of the text is truncated. Swap the TextView and ImageView - and the text is ellipsis-shortened as needed.

Why does it work so? And how to fix this?

Style:

```
    <style name="TextView.TeamCode">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinearLayout` doesn't handle this situation very well... I mean if you have first child like that (with `wrap_content`) and you want it to stop expanding when it reaches `{parent_width}-{next_child_width}`. Unfortunately it will stop with width=`{parent_width}`.
 So, if the text will be bigger, the left bound of view will move outside of it's parent (to the left, but keeping the right bound in place) and the beginning of text will be cut (because view is drawn partially outside od parent left bound). If the text will also not fit the parent width - text will also be cut from the right side, but this time with ellipsize (...)

You can see the results here:
[image]

Try something like that:

```
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_team_code"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:text="Super long text"/>
```

By applying the weight `TextView` will occupy all the remaining space (with fixed width) and will not be pushed outside because text won't fit inside. To keep the right alignment you can also add:

```
            android:gravity="right"
```

Comment: android:gravity="right" does not work with ellipsize:"end" :(

Comment: @Maciej Ciemięga what if I am using RelativeLayout rather than LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

**android:singleLine="true"** is obsolete.

Instead of

> ```
> android:singleLine="true"
> android:ellipsize="end"
> ```

you have to use

```
android:gravity="right"
android:inputType="text"
```